# pam_access using netgroup for host origin

Tags: pam, rhel6, rhel7

I would like to be able to use:

```
+ : @user_netgroup : @host_netgroup
```

in my access.conf, but this seems to fail due to pam_access not supporting host netgroups.  If I substitute an IP or fully qualified hostname in to replace the @host_netgroup, it works as expected (we are already using @user_netgroup extensively, and have no problem with that).

Is there a way to modify pam_access to allow host netgroups in the access.conf origin?

OS: RHEL6 and RHEL7